# Average rate of change for $f (x) = 2x^2 + 1$ on $[x, x + h]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to answer a question from the [OpenStax Precalculus](https://openstax.org/details/books/precalculus) book. The question is #9, section 1.3, pdf page 48.

My calculation is:

$$\frac{(2x^2+2h^2+1)-(2x^2+1)}{(x + h) - (x)}$$

Giving $2h$.

However, the book says the answer is $4x + 2h$ and I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: $2(x+h)^2 \neq 2x^{2} + h^{2}$

Comment: As soon as I saw your comment it became blindingly obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$\frac{2(x+h)^2+1-2x^2-1}{h}=\frac{2x^2+4xh+2h^2-2x^2}{h}$$

Comment: Thank you,just corrected!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2(x+h)^2+1-(2x^2+1)}{(x + h) - (x)} =\frac{2(x^2+2xh+h^2)+1-(2x^2+1)}{(x + h) - (x)}=$$

$$\frac{4xh+2h^2}{ h}=4x+2h$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align} f(x+h)=&2(x+h)^2+1 \\ =&2(x^2+2xh+h^2)+1 \\ =& 2x^2+4xh+2h^2+1 \end{align}
Then
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{(2x^2+4xh+2h^2+1)-(2x^2+1)}{h}=\frac{h(4x+2h)}{h}=4x+2h$$
if we consider $h\neq 0$.